# Facebook Valid OAuth Redirect URIs Is not working redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed

Tags: php, facebook-login

I have tried to login with facebook but it's given following error

```
"URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs"
```

I have added following things in developer facebook account.

Basic setting add domain name like `mytest.net` then add web site URL like `https://mytest.net`

ANd finally facebook login setting page i have added same URL `https://mytest.net` in Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

But it's not work.

Comment: You need the **full** URL. Not `https://mytest.net`, but `https://mytest.net/the/file/that/handles/things.php` or whatever your full URL for your OAuth flow is.

Comment: Take the URL of the error message - it'll be something like `https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?client_id=12345&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Findex.php&scope=stuff`. Make sure the `redirect_uri` part is **exactly** what's in your app settings, including http vs. https, capitalization, etc.